# Removing Category from left nav Magento

Tags: xml, magento, navigation

I want to remove a category from the left navigation in magento, however i want it to remain in the main navigation top.phtml. So far the only way I can think to do this is with a bit of XML in the local.xml Like so:

```
    <reference name="catalog.leftnav">
        <action method="unsetChild"><alias>Item to remove</alias></action>
    </reference>
```

However I don't know the alias of the item i want to unset. The category name is:

To purchase from US online store

& the url is:

to-purchase-from-us-online-store

If anyone could help with this it would be awesome, I have just lost the plot completely.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try setting Is Anchor to No?

Comment: yeah, i tried this. But it removed it from 2 places. I ended up using this: jQuery(".pcl-items-menu li span:contains('To purchase from US online store')").parent().hide(); I know its not pretty but.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsetting via the XML will not help you in this case, that will only disable the whole block, ie the full left navigation.

there's no way (out of the box) to disable a single category on the top nav and not the left nav.

There's a few approaches you could take, although some would be overkill for what you need I am guessing, a simple dirty approach would be:

You could always copy Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation to the local namespance (app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php)

You could then rename this (Navigationleft.php) and make changes as you require. You would then change the XML statement to use this new block for the left nav

```
<reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/navigationleft" 
               name="catalog.leftnav" 
               after="currency" 
               template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"
         />
</reference>
```

You could always add a new attribute to the Catalog entity and modify the Navigation to use this (show_on_left_nav) along with is_active when showing the items, although this is probably a bit overkill :)

Comment: Thanks for that, looks as though most of this is overkill, especially when it comes to messing with the core. Problem is the magento build isn't originally mine, so I have to deal with what I already had. I may just do it hacky and jQuery it to hide. I did wonder if i could just find that category ID and then in the template>catalog>navigation>left.phtml add to foreach if in this category don't show.

Answer (score 1):

This is very old question but it can help to any one who have same stuff like me.

To Remove category list from sidebar you can modify xml files as below.

## Remove from layered navigation:

Add below code in `local.xml` file if theme have such file:

```
<catalog_category_layered>
     <reference name="catalog.leftnav">           
        <action method="unsetChild">
            <child>category_filter</child>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Add below code in `catalog.xml` file if `local.xml` not exists:

```
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
    <action method="unsetChild">
        <child>category_filter</child>
    </action>       
</block>
```

## Remove from category default page:

Add below code in `local.xml` file if theme have such file:

```
<reference name="catalog.leftnav" >       
    <action method="unsetChild">
         <child>category_filter</child>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Add below code in `catalog.xml` file if `local.xml` not exists:

```
 <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml">
   <action method="unsetChild">
         <child>category_filter</child>
    </action>
 </block>
```

## Remove from catalog search page:

Add below code in `local.xml` file if theme have such file:

```
<catalogsearch_result_index>
   <reference name="catalog.leftnav">           
        <action method="unsetChild">
            <child>category_filter</child>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalogsearch_result_index>
```

Add below code in `catalogsearch.xml` file if `local.xml` not exists:

```
<block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
      <action method="unsetChild">
            <child>category_filter</child>
        </action>
</block>
```

**Note:** Please clear your cache if you have enabled it in your admin.